# Event when order created from backend

Tags: magento2, event-observer, admin-order-create

I've used `sales_order_place_after` to get order id after order placed from backend but it doesnt return order id. Not sure what's missing here.

Here's my observer

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        echo $orderId = $order->getId();  exit;
    }
```

Above code executed but if it doesnt print order id.

Any suggestions for this ? For all those who are curious I need to store order data after order plaed into custom table.

Comment: make sure you place events.xml under etc/adminhtml

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes I was able to solve issue.

Answer (score 1):

add observer only for admin `app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="sales_order_place_after">
            <observer name="load_custom_handler" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\GetOrder" />
        </event>
    </config>
```

add observer file `app\code\Vendor\Module\Observer\GetOrder.php`

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class GetOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $orderFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderFactory)
    {
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $orderId= $orderIds[0]; //Do your logic here

        $order = $this->orderFactory->load($orderId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not working cant able to get order id error is "An ID is needed. Set the ID and try again."

Comment: i've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to just change your code like this.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        echo $orderId = $order->getId();  
        exit;
}
```

Comment: Its not working cant able to get order id error is "An ID is needed. Set the ID and try again."

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

Set logger to print order id.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class Index implements ObserverInterface
{
     protected $scopeConfig;
     protected $logger;

     public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
        ) {
             $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
             $this->logger = $logger;
       }

      public function execute(Observer $observer)
      { 
            //get order ID
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $orderId = $order->getId();
            $this->logger->info("order id:".$orderId);

            //get order orderIncrement Id
            $orderIncrementid = $order->getIncrementId();
            $this->logger->info("orderIncrement ID".$orderIncrementid."");

      } 
  }
```